# How to get the id and v-text of a select vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

how can I get the id, and in turn the value of the v-text to save it in a table

I want to save the `id` of the `malla_curricular` table in the field `idMalla` and the value of the fields `pAcademicoInicio` `cicloLectivoInicio`in the field `periodoLectivoMallaOrigen` of the table `estudio_reingreso`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FksPI.png)

```
<Label>Seleccione el periodo de la malla</Label>
 <select v-model="idMalla" class="form-control col-md-12">
  <option v-for="malla in arrayPeriodo" :key="malla.id" :value="malla.id" v-text="malla.pAcademicoInicio + ' - ' + malla.cicloLectivoInicio">

 </option>
```

The vue method is here where I don't know how to get the values to send them to the other table

```
EventSubir(){
let me = this;
axios.post('/estudioreingresomat/registrar',{     
    'id': this.id,    
    'idMalla': this.idMalla,
    'periodoLectivoMallaOrigen': this.periodoLectivoMallaOrigen,
    'periodoLectivoMallRediseñada': this.periodoLectivoMallRediseñada,
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log('EXITO!!');    
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('error al ingresar el estudio!!');
    console.log(error);
});
},


public function store(Request $request)    {
   if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');
   try{
        DB::beginTransaction();
        $estudioReingreso = new EstudioReingreso();
        $estudioReingreso->idMalla = $request->idMalla;
        $estudioReingreso->periodoLectivoMallaOrigen = $request->periodoLectivoMallaOrigen; 
        $estudioReingreso->periodoLectivoMallRediseñada = $request->periodoLectivoMallRediseñada; 
        $estudioReingreso->save();
        session(['estudioReingreso' => $estudioReingreso->id]); 

        DB::commit();

    } catch (Exception $e){
    echo('se tosteo lpm');
    DB::rollBack();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I am assuming that you already fetched the data for arrayPeriodo)

If this is how you structured your data, then you can access the `malla_selected` object from which will contain what you say is `:value` in your option tag.

template:

```
<Label>Seleccione el periodo de la malla</Label>
<select v-model="selected_malla" class="form-control col-md-12"> <!-- changed idMalla to selected_malla, then in the option - the :value becomes the object itself -->
    <option
        v-for="malla in arrayPeriodo"
        :key="malla.id"
        :value="malla"
        v-text="malla.pAcademicoInicio + ' - ' + malla.cicloLectivoInicio">
    </option>
```

vue component:

```js
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            malla_selected: null
            arrayPeriodo: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    idMalla: 2,
                    pAcademicoInicio: 'foo',
                    cicloLectivoInicio: 'bar',
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    methods:{
        EventSubir(){
            axios.post('/estudioreingresomat/registrar',{
                'id': malla_selected.id,
                'idMalla': malla_selected.idMalla,
                'periodoLectivoMallaOrigen': malla_selected.periodoLectivoMallaOrigen,
                'periodoLectivoMallRediseñada': malla_selected.periodoLectivoMallRediseñada,
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log('EXITO!!');
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log('error al ingresar el estudio!!');
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
}
```